# SPSS 22: looping through 4000 text files and parsing data out of it

Tags: spss

Unfortunately, Stata does does not recognize UTF8/Unicode. Fortunately, SPSS 22 does! I'm trying to parse specific rows containing variables with weird characters out of +/- 4000 .txt files. Thus far, I have only managed to do it with only 1 .txt file with the following code:

```
* First, get the text files.
GET DATA  /TYPE=TXT 
/FILE="\my\path\20001_friends.txt" 
/ENCODING='UTF8' 
/DELCASE=LINE 
/DELIMITERS=" " 
/ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED 
/FIRSTCASE=1 
/IMPORTCASE=ALL 
/VARIABLES= 
V1 A2082 
V2 A2118 
V3 A27 
V4 A36 
V5 A113 
V6 A54 
V7 A49 
V8 A47 
V9 A78 
V10 A109 
V11 A33 
V12 A15 
V13 A81 
V14 A4 
V15 A21 
V16 A7. 
CACHE. 
EXECUTE. 
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.

* Second, compute conditional upon Vriend = 1.
COMPUTE x = 0.
IF (V5 = "Vriend") x = 1.
COMPUTE y = 1.
EXECUTE.

* Third, get every observation after Vriend.
IF y ~= lag(x) z = 0.
IF y = lag(x) z = 1.
EXECUTE.

* Fourth, select only the names.
SELECT IF z = 1.
EXECUTE.
```

I want to do this for +/- 4000 of files and end with an appended list of rows of all the rows I parsed from this text files (while deleting the rest). Also, the text files go from 20001_names.txt to 36872_names.txt, so not every identifier is available. e.g., 20002_names.txt might be missing, whilst 20003_names.txt might exist. I also want to construct a variable indicating the identifier from which the row came from (e.g., id = 20001 for all the rows parsed from the first file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution is to use the SPSSINC PROCESS FILES extension command to iterate over the 4000 files.  On each pass you can merge the result with the data to date.  The input list can be a wildcard such as c:\myfiles*.txt.  No need to enumerate all the files.  On each iteration, you can use the JOB_INPUTFILE file handle reference to open the current file.

This command requires the Python Essentials.  See the SPSS Community (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral) website for details.  The Essentials are free, but the installation process varies by version.

If you have Statistics V22, you probably already have the Essentials and can just install PROCESS FILES from the Utilities > Extension Bundles menu.